# nginx - Attempt to redirect path with variable internally fails

Tags: nginx, rewrite

i would like to redirect the request to a file from

```
/path/to/file/content?path=file.pdf
```

to

```
/new/path/to/file/file.pdf
```

under the same domain.

I tried simple rewrite rules or like this.

```
location ~ ^/path/to/file/content?path=(.*) {
   return 301 /new/path/to/file/$1;
}
```

Unfortunately, nginx does not understand the variable. What am I doing wrong? Does anyone have a tip for me, please? Unfortunately, I don't know much about reqex.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike apache rewrite rules both `location` and `rewrite` nginx directives works with so-called *normalized* URI (see the `location` directive [documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) to find out what does it mean) which does not include the query part. Check if the `path` query argument is not empty and do a redirect if the request URI matches your pattern using the following configuration fragment:

```
if ($arg_path) {
    rewrite ^/path/to/file/content /new/path/to/file/$arg_path? permanent;
}
```

Comment: Hello Ivan, thank you very much for your answer. I copied the fragment into the block
location / { }
But then nginx ignores this rule. But if I delete the if part, i.e. write only rewrite...., the redirection almost works. The browser then only says /new/path/to/file/, but the file name is missing.

Comment: Sorry, of course it is my typo, it should be `$arg_path` instead of `$arg_file`.

Comment: All is well, you help me a lot. Thank you very much. Now the if statement works. Unfortunately, the address in the browser still ends at /new/path/to/file/. The file name is missing.

Comment: The end user browsers usually cache permanent HTTP 301 redirects, so it can be cached URI from the previous configuration. Clear your browser cache or try from the incognito window.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, how stupid of me. You made my day, thank you very much!